# Firebase real database values differ from the retrieved ones

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So, in realtime database I have:

[image]

When I retrieve data from database I get:

[image]

Model class looks like:

```
public class User implements Parcelable {
    public static final Parcelable.Creator<User> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<User>() {
        @Override
        public User createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new User(source);
        }

        @Override
        public User[] newArray(int size) {
            return new User[size];
        }
    };
    
    ...
    private String hasToPayFromPastRides;
    private String didNotPayCount;
    ...;

    public User() {

    }

    public User(..., String didNotPayCount, String hasToPayFromPastRides) {
        ...
        this.didNotPayCount = didNotPayCount;
        this.hasToPayFromPastRides = hasToPayFromPastRides;
    }

    protected User(Parcel in) {
        ...
        this.didNotPayCount = in.readString();
        this.hasToPayFromPastRides = in.readString();
    }

    ...

    public String getDidNotPayCount() {
        return didNotPayCount;
    }

    public void setDidNotPayCount(String didNotPayCount) {
        this.didNotPayCount = didNotPayCount;
    }

    public String hasToPayFromPastRides() {
        return hasToPayFromPastRides;
    }

    public void setHasToPayFromPastRides(String hasToPayFromPastRides) {
        this.hasToPayFromPastRides = hasToPayFromPastRides;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(this.userId);
        dest.writeString(this.userFullName);
        dest.writeString(this.userEmail);
        dest.writeString(this.userPhoneNumber);
        dest.writeString(this.userAvatarUrl);
        dest.writeString(this.userLocalAvatar);
        dest.writeString(this.userAddress);
        dest.writeString(this.userCity);
        dest.writeString(this.userArea);
        dest.writeString(this.userPostalCode);
        dest.writeString(this.userRating);
        dest.writeString(this.userTotalRating);
        dest.writeString(this.totalTrips);
        dest.writeString(this.riskCount);
        dest.writeString(this.isBlocked);
        dest.writeString(this.isDefaulter);
        dest.writeString(this.pendingRating);
        dest.writeParcelable(this.pendingRateObj, flags);
        dest.writeString(this.didNotPayCount);
        dest.writeString(this.hasToPayFromPastRides);
    }
}
```

What surprises me is that one value gets read correctly "didNotPayCount" when "hasToPayFromPastRides" is null. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your getter isn't named correctly:

```
public String hasToPayFromPastRides()
```

It should be:

```
public String getHasToPayFromPastRides()
```

Comment: The name of the getters and setters must match the names of the properties.  There is no room for variation.  This is a standard JavaBeans specification.